How to transform DE into Clairauts DE?
How to transform differential equation of the form
$$y^2 +x^2 \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2 - 2xy \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) = 4 \left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}\right)^2$$
into Clairauts differential equation of the form
$$y = x \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)+f \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) \quad ?$$
An attempt to transform it by writing the left side of DE as a square:
$$y^2 - 2xy\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) +x^2\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2  = 4\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}\right)^2$$
$$\left(y - x\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)\right)^2 = 4\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}\right)^2$$
$$y - x\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) = 2\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} \right) $$
$$y  = x\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) + 2\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} \right)  $$
So the given DE in Clairauts form:
$$y  = x\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) + 2\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} \right)^{-1}  $$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hint: write the LHS as a square.

@Pranay I did but I am unsure if the form I got is enough for Clairauts DE form...

To answer the question at the end, yes!

This is not Clairauts ODE.   The f function has to be non-linear in $y'$. Yours is linear. This is separable ode.

@Nasser WolframAlpha declares the equation y=x(dy/dx)+2((dy/dx)^(-1)) as a "first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation" and "Clairaut's equation".
I was given the task of solving a Clairauts DE, so I first had to transform it into one and then solve it, which I did.

The ode y=x(dy/dx)+2((dy/dx)^(-1))  is not the same as the one you showed. This is Cairaut, yes, since the $f$ function is non-linear in $y'$. Your original ode is not. The first step is to solve for $y$.  This will result in 2 odes since ode is quadratic in $y$. You will see that each of these ode's is a separable ode. So I do not understand what the HW means by converting to Cairaut.

@Nasser this exercise was from my DE homework, under Clairauts. My teacher often gives the wrong form of DE and we have to reconstruct it to the right one to solve it like one.

If you managed to figure how to convert it to Clairauts, you can post it as answer. I do not see how myself. But who knows, my be there is a trick.

@Nasser just edited the post to include it!

Sorry, I actually read your original ODE as having all $\frac{dy}{dx}$ terms ! I did not notice that the last term was $\frac{dx}{dy}$.  So what did looks correct now.
